# Ionic 2: Detecting changes from tab components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an app where each tab of the tab layout pertains to different aspects of a given client's attributes (i.e. profile, financials, etc.).  When a change occurs to the client, I'd like the parent component to be able to detect it.

It seems the only input for passing data to the tabs is through `[rootParams]="foo"` but I do not know how to detect changes to `foo` in the parent.

`ngOnChanges()` does not seem to fire when there is an update to `foo`. I believe I'll need to use `Observables` just not sure how to implement that.

Here's what I have so far.   After selecting a client from the index we move to the tab component:

**Tab Component (ClientGenericPage)**

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'client-generic.html'
})

export class ClientGenericPage {
  client:any;
  constructor(
    public navParams: NavParams ) {

    this.client = navParams.get('client');
    this.clientParams = {
      client: this.client
    }
}

<ion-tabs class="tabs-basic">
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Profile" [root]="profilePage" tabIcon="user-o" [rootParams]="clientParams" #profile></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Weigh Ins" [root]="weighinsPage" tabIcon="scale-bathroom" [rootParams]="clientParams" #weighins></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Finance" [root]="financePage" [tabBadge]="alerts.financial" tabBadgeStyle="danger" tabIcon="attach-money" [rootParams]="clientParams" #finance></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Images" [root]="imagePage" [tabBadge]="alerts.images" tabBadgeStyle="danger" tabIcon="fa-image" [rootParams]="clientParams" #images></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

I then make updates in the child tabs.  For instance in the first tab `ProfilePage`.

```
export class ClientDetailsPage {
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    private filterObject: FilterObject, 
    public http: Http,
    public modalController: ModalController,
    private clientService: ClientService,
    private app: App
  ) {
    this.client = navParams.get('client');

  // Example function where I make an update to client
  updateForm(fab) {
    this.clientService.update(this.client, "client", this.token)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.client = data
          this.clientService.handleResponse("Successfully updated the client!")
        },
        err => this.clientService.handleResponse("Ut oh.. couldn't update the client!"),
        () => fab.close()
      )
  }
```

**How do I alert the parent that client has changed, so that other tabs are updated as well?**

Comment: Seems you are looking for `@Output`? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: In other words to emit an event anytime a change occurs?  It seems so repetitive and I'm not even sure where to listen for the event since the parent isn't really the tab component

Comment: Well we have basically nothing to work with, since you have not presented any code, and just with comment that *I don't know how to detect changes in foo*. So any better answer I cannot give. But the link I gave presents your (other) options quite well. As a sidenote, with output you can also decide when you want to emit the changes.

Comment: It's difficult to provide the relevant code without providing the code to multiple components.. but I'll edit and try to explain what's going on

Comment: What is the purpose of listening in the parent??

Comment: I need the sibling components to know there has been a change

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of events feature here. You can fire the event like this

```
this.events.publish('functionCall:onClick', event);
```

and subscribe the event published like this in your target page

```
this.events.subscribe('functionCall:onClick', eventData => {
  //do something
});
```